# How many seforim are attributed to the Rebbe?

Tags: jewish-books, chabad, authorship

How many seforim are attributed to R' Menachem Mendel Schneerson, z"l? Like a total of all his talks writings etc.

Does he have the most published seforim out of all gedolim?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39467/discussion-on-question-by-menachem-how-many-seforim-are-attributed-to-the-rebbe).

Comment: The introduction to HaYom Yom has the complete count. I don't have it handly, and Hebrewbooks.org only has an old edition. In terms of "most published" you have to have some criteria. Beyond letters, he wrote very little, mostly edited writeups of what he spoke. He was much more prolific as a teacher by talking than writing.

Answer (score 2):

On [Hebrewbooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx) i made a search (of scanned books) for author

שניאורסון, מנחם מנדל, 1902

I  get **322**
(some of them have the same  sicha/maamar/point printed in 2 different books (sometimes translated differently or just in different orders))

Answer (score 1):

> Does he have the most published seforim out of all gedolim?

Many of 'his' books are (near-)transcriptions of what he said, in many cases not even corrected by him ("בלתי מוגה"). Since God taught the complete explanation of *Chumash* (plus some other stuff) to Moses at Sinai, the *gadol* with the most published books is הקל הגדול.

Comment: @hazoriz No, just a poorly asked question.

Comment: So Hashem only wrote one book

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, no, He wrote _Likute Sichos_ and _Haamek Davar_ and _Sifse Chachamim_ and….

Comment: Source for claim about extent of Sinaic teachings?

Comment: @mevaqesh, I'll try to find it _b'li neder_.

Comment: @msh210 Oh, there are plenty of sources. My point was just that rationalist Rishonim reject those sources.

Answer (score 1):

The Rebbe didn't actually write many seforim. He wrote hayom yom in the name of the Friediker Rebbe and a Haggadah (and I think he also wrote a biography of the Rebbe Maharash).

igros kodesh is from his letters, which I think some were written by him and some were dictated to the secretary. The rest is from his sichos (speeches) and ma'amorim (chassidus discourses), that he said but didn't write. some he edited (like all lekutei sichos) and some he didn't. You have many seforim containing his sichos and mamorim, whether they're sorted differently, or adapted, explained etc.